# How I can compile FFTW library with Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, fftw

I am trying compile FFTW with Microsoft Visual Studio. I have version 2010 Express and Community 2013. I download files from http://www.fftw.org/install/windows.html. I open solution, choose project libfftw-3.3 and is error "The build tools for Windows7.1SDK (Platform Toolset = 'Windows7.1SDK') cannot be found" In properties I change Platform Toolset to Visual Studio 2013. When I try build, it not found fftw_mkprinter_cnt and fftw_mkprinter_str. 
When I change Platform Toolset to Visual Studio 2010 is error "cannot open file VCOMPD.lib". When I trying ignore this library, appears errors as before (fftw_mkprinter_cnt and fftw_mkprinter_str)
How can I compile this library

Answer (score 5):

Add mkprinter-str.c to both the libfftw-3.3 and the libfftwf-3.3 projects.

This worked for me along with changing the Platform Toolset to Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 0):

This thread is actually seriously outdated and I guess a lot of people might be searching for a solution to this but with the latest version of Visual Studio, 2019. In case it helps anyone -- I posted detailed and tested steps in another thread: [Use FFTW with Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35517892/use-fftw-with-visual-studio-2015)